# memtest86 5.31b Memory Type Unknown

Tags: memory, hp-pavilion, memtest86+

I have HP c7000 chassis with gen9 blade and have 4x16G (total 16GB) memory. HP iLO saying you have degraded so i start running memory test using memtest86 5.31b and its been 1 hour and it did 5 test but didn't detected anything wrong so does memtest86 5.31b is lying?

[image]

Does using latest version of memtest86 will help, reason i am running older because its already configured for PXE boot. (newer version doesn't support PXE until you buy it)

Comment: What configurations are you using with `Memtest`? Maybe do a longer 12hr+ soak test. Or edit the ECC check https://www.memtest86.com/tech_configuring-memtest.html

Comment: does memtest86 v9.x free version support PXE? I have lots of HP server and i can't mount USB drive on each remotely.  I need PXE support